# Finding total number of members in each group in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of groups and a table of members, that links back to the groups table.
Is there a way to run a query that returns each group with the number of members in that group?

Answer (score 2):

```
select group_id, count(group_id) as group_count
from members
group by group_id
order by group_count desc
```

Comment: Useful, but ignores a couple cases: What if some groups have no members? What if some members are not associated with a group?

Comment: LEFT JOIN groups table with members table then group by groups_table.id

Comment: thanks that works.  However i would like to use INNER join to pull information from the group table.  is that possible in this case?

Comment: INNER JOIN will ignore groups that have no members