# Group MySQL values from table

Tags: mysql

I'm sure this is possible I don't know where to start.
I have a table with 2000 values they are on the range from 0 to 100.
I want to query the table to get the different groups of values.
i.e. I have those values 5, 10 , 5 , 2 , 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 2

I want an output like this:

```
 Value - Number_of_times 
   0            1
   1            5
   2            3
   5            2
  10            2
```

Comment: Have you done any research at all? This is a fairly simple query.

Comment: I did, I'm new in SQL and checked mysql official page. Tried lots of examples they have there and did not work. and of course google it.

Comment: Say that in the future. Lets people know you at least tried. :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [finding total number of members for each group in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278367/finding-total-number-of-members-for-each-group-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your results by your field, and take the [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) of each group:

```
SELECT   myfield, COUNT(*) as number_of_times
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY myfield
```

Comment: I tried something similar to your query and did not work!!! but yours works just fine..